# How can I acquire fish filet?

Tags: new-world

A quest requires me to acquire 70 fish filet.

I found the place where to fish and have fish. How can I turn the fish into fish filet?

Answer (score 4):

Fish filet is obtained by salvaging different species of fish.

In order to salvage fish, right click on your fish and click "salvage" or use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + Left Click on an item to salvage.

Comment: Please accept your own answer.